# Uploading customized template to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could I upload a template created by Virtualbox+Vagrant to AWS?

What would the right way be?

I know I can do an AMI from the Instances which are already installed on AWS but I want to perform my own configuration on an OS  and then upload the image to AWS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWS VM Import/Export, some VM types can be imported into AWS. Only the following disk types are supported:

- OVA
- VMDK
- VHD
- RAW

There is a big list of prerequisites that must be met in order to successfully import a VM:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html

If your VirtualBox VM does not meet these requirements, then you're out of luck. Otherwise, you can upload your VM to S3, then import using the AWS CLI.

Information about the VM Import/Export feature can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instances_of_your_vm.html